# Is there a way I can redirect the commits to the master copy of SVN , while my SVN is pointed to the mirror(read only) copy

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have set up a mirror of our existing repo which syncs .
But As I understand the mirror copy changes are only to be made by svnsync.

So the plan is to have all the users point to mirror repo but the commits need to be to master repo. But I cannot ask the users to switch between this repo every time they have to commit or checkout.

So is there a way , either in the client side or on the server side hook script where I could redirect the commits to master repo

THe repos are not served using Apache so  I think the SVNMasterURI or those solutions wont work , and we use svn protocol and not http or https

Comment: Did you know about hooks (on server-side)?

Comment: Yes, But I can just stop the users from committing to repo, I cannot redirect to a different repo ryt??

Answer (score 0):

### Preface

1. You try to use *CVCS*-system in *DVCS*-style. This is **The Bad Idea (tm)** in common, because it ignore "Make your own business" principle
2. You added additional layer of complexity (repo-mirror) without visible added layer of usefulness (mirror "just exist" and give you only headache)

### Face

Anyway, you have *some* solution**s**, more or less ugly and|or native

**Level0: change nothing in infrastructure**

- Prepare, publish, teach end-users use custom command (with any name) instead of plain `svn ci`. This script have to perform all switches behind the scene, something like

  `svn relocate $MAINREPO`

  `svn ci -m $1`

  `svn relocate $MIRRORREPO`
- Try to intercept all data with server-side pre-commit hook (just idea, without ready to use code)

**Level1: changes on user-side**

If you have DVCS-tasks, you can use DVCS-clients. The most known and mentioned are Git and Mercurial, both can easy work with remote SVN-repos, but HG can't work (AFAIK) with two SVN-repos from single local, while Git can. You have to install, configure, teach user to use Git and, after all, they'll "fetch" from $MIRRORREPO, but "push" to $MAINREPO

**Level2: full migration to DVCS**

Replace all with Mercurial (both repos and user's tools), add both paths to clents's configuration, pull from $MIRRORREPO, push to $MAINREPO

Comment: Great!! I have the pre-commit hook scripts written for Toroise client to relocate back and forth , but unfortunately i have to configure for each path. Is there a way I can have a common hook script for all commits !